# Using MAGMI IGNORE with "Default Values setter"

Tags: php, magento, csv, import, magmi

I am using Magmi to import and update products in Magento. In CSV file sometimes cells are empty and i dont want Magmi to overwrite existing products data if CSV has empty cells.

I have followed instructions here: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=MAGMI_IGNORE

It says i can ignore empty cells using `__MAGMI_IGNORE__` in cells. This works if i insert manually in CSV file, but i need to have this inserted dynamically.

In "Default values setter" i have tried to insert this for column short_description:

```
{{ {item.short_description}==""?"__MAGMI_IGNORE__":{item.short_description} }}
```

When i save the profile it strips out everything after first doubble quote so it looks like this:

```
{{ {item.short_description}==
```

I have then tried changing to single quote like this:

```
{{ {item.short_description}==''?'__MAGMI_IGNORE__':{item.short_description} }}
```

Now i am able to save profile without Magmi removing code but when i run profile i still replace short description with empty, when it is supposed to ignore cell because settings in "Default value setter".

This is my settings:

> CSV separator: ,
>
> CSV Enclosure: "

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas you are using are not for "default value setter" plugin but for "Value Replacer" plugin.

Comment: Thx this solved my problem. Also thanks alot for very nice module :)
Another thing, it still removes all chars after first doubble quote so needed to replace with single quotes to get it working.